# Create Datastream entity with phenomenonTime using SensorUp (SensorThings API implementation)

Tags: iot, sensorthings

I am trying to create a datastream using SensorUp with the phenomenon as shown in line 13 of the attached image, the response to the datastream does not contain the phenomenonTime:

[Datastream creation with PhenomenonTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ug3.jpg)

Can someone advise how I can create the Datastream entity with the phenomenonTime? My understanding is that if the phenomenonTime is not provided, the standard picks up the time when the Datastream was created. However while querying for the Datastream, the phenomenonTime is not included in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Datastream - PhenomenonTime is defined as: "The temporal interval of the phenomenon times of all observations belonging to this Datastream"

Last time I checked the Datastream - PhenomenonTime was not working on the SensorUp site.

At the moment we are working on an opensource SensorThings implementation GOST (https://github.com/Geodan/gost), support for Datastream - PhenomenonTime (and ResultTime) should be in next release 0.5